# Add column corresponding to file of origin when reading in many csv files in R

Tags: r, csv, fread

I am reading csv files from a list into one dataset, using

```
x <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list, fread))
```

I would like to add a column in `x` which indicates the name of the file corresponding to each row .

`list` looks like this:

```
[[1]] '~/amsterdam.csv'
[[2]] '~/atlanta.csv'
[[3]] '~/bangalore.csv'
```

I would like `x` to look like this

```
 V1   V2           city
2.5   3.4   '~/amsterdam.csv'
5.4   1.1   '~/bangalore.csv'
3.4   2.9   '~/atlanta.csv'
0.5   9.8   '~/bangalore.csv'
```

Is there a way, with the command I used, to link each row of x to the file from which it originates?

I am currently using a loop to do this (reading in the file, then adding a column corresponding to the file name, then binding all files together), but I was wondering whether there was a faster and cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this should work:

```
myFread <- function(fileName){
    data.frame(
        fread(fileName)
        , "city" = fileName
    )
}
```

and then of course this

```
x <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list, fread))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `data.table` try `rbindlist` instead of `do.call(rbind...`.You can add a new column `City` using `idcol` parameter which will have an index for each dataframe that can be given value later from `list`.  Also note that `list` is an internal function in R and it is better to avoid using it as a variable name.

```
library(data.table)

x <- rbindlist(lapply(list, fread), idcol = "City")
x[, City := basename(list)[City]]
```

Answer (score 0):

with `data.table`

```r
all <- list.files(wd, full = T, pattern = "csv")
l <- lapply(all, function(x) {data.table(fread(x), "filename" = x)})
# Eventually do something on all columns
lapply(l, function (x) { x[, filename := basename(filename)] })
dt <- rbindlist( l )
```